# CSS error Linear Gradient from colorzilla editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a linear gradient from colorzilla that says it is for old version. Pls.. I would like to ask for help on how i will convert this codes that is compatible for newer version or what will be the new codes for this. Thank you Maam/Sir. I am a beginner in html and css.

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: 
http://colorzilla.com/gradient- 
editor/#fbfaf6+9,d4cebf+74,d4cebf+74,d4cebf+100 */
background: rgb(251,250,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(251,250,246,1) 9%, 
rgba(212,206,191,1) 74%, rgba(212,206,191,1) 74%, 
rgba(212,206,191,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(251,250,246,1) 
9%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 74%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 
74%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(251,250,246,1) 
9%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 74%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 
74%,rgba(212,206,191,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, 
Opera12+, Safari7+ */
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What do you need to change regarding the code? The actual `linear-gradient` line is completely valid CSS. What are you trying to make it compatible with?

Comment: The comment says for old browsers, those are all fallbacks for different browsers, it includes code for modern browsers as well.